# Use the result of a calculation in the same formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to accomplish something in Excel (latest version), I've googled for a while now, but probably I'm describing the problem not accurately enough.

I want to perform a calculation in Excel:

Known value A: 100
Known value B: 1.4

I want achieve do the following: (A * B) + ((Result of A * B) * B) + ((Result of A*B*B) * B)

The calculation steps behind this would be:

1. 100 * 1.4 = 140
2. 140 * 1.4 = 196
3. 196 * 1.4 = 274.4
4. = 140 + 196 + 274.4 = 610.4

I can easily do this using 4 cells, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this with 1 formula? I've experimented with the LET function, but can't seem to achieve it with this function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Apologies if I have misunderstood you but isn't this what you are trying? `=(A1 * B1) + ((A1 * B1) * B1) + ((A1*B1*B1) * B1)`

Comment: Latest version? Let's make it way too convoluted: `=SUM(SCAN(A1,SEQUENCE(3),LAMBDA(a,b,a*B1)))`

Comment: @SiddharthRout you are right actually... Didn't think it was that simple :D Thank you!

Comment: And this will work in all versions of Excel :D

Comment: `=A1*B1+A1*B1^2+A1*B1^3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `LET`:

```
=LET(x,A1*B1,
     y,x*B1,
     z,y*B1,
     SUM(x,y,z)
    )
```

[image]

If you don't have the `LET` function, other methods:

```
=SUM(A1*B1^{1,2,3})
=SUMPRODUCT(A1*B1^{1,2,3})
```

Comment: `=SUM(A1*B1^SEQUENCE(3))` ... I'll delete my answer since that is similar to the "other methods", though if one doesn't have `LET` idk if `SEQUENCE` will be available either.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so it seems I did something wrong with the LET function as I kept receiving errors, but this worked brilliantly!! Thanks!

Comment: @BigBen I think they both appeared at the same time in 365 and 2021

Comment: I love the `SUM`-solution. Can't get any shorter.